# Only one of three files getting uploaded

Tags: php, file-upload

I'm trying to upload three files to my local server simultaneously. Here's the script:

```
   <form method="post" action="<?php echo($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" >

Note: All files are mandatory <br/><br/>

<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="30000" />

Select first image: <input name="img[]" type="file"/> <br/>
Select second image: <input name="img[]" type="file"/> <br/>
Select third image: <input name="img[]" type="file"/> <br/>

<br/><br/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Go!"/>
</form>

<?php

if (isset($_FILES)) {

    for ($key=0; $key<=2; $key++)
    {
        $tmp_name = $_FILES["img"]["tmp_name"][$key];
        $name = $_FILES["img"]["name"][$key];
        move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "img/$name");
    }


    echo "Done!";   
}

?>
```

I am facing two problems:

1. As soon as the page loads, I'm getting a notice saying `Undefined
   index: img`
2. Only the second file is getting uploaded.

Any idea what is going wrong?

Comment: Have you var_dump'd your $_FILES structure (or examined it in a step-debugger) to see what's going on?

Comment: Here it is: `Array ( [img] => Array ( [name] => Array ( [0] => 1.jpg [1] => 2.jpg [2] => 3.jpg ) [type] => Array ( [0] => [1] => image/jpeg [2] => ) [tmp_name] => Array ( [0] => [1] => /opt/lampp/temp/phpspbdSN [2] => ) [error] => Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 0 [2] => 2 ) [size] => Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 11721 [2] => 0 ) ) )`
Looks like there's something wrong with the type of first and third files. But I can see them all right in the image viewer.

Comment: Ah, got it! The file sizes were exceeding the limit defined in the hidden field. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction! Now, how do I deal with the undefined index notice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting error 2, the files are too big, only the second one is small enough:

Read this under File Uploads:
http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize

Comment: Just did that. Thanks for answering! Any idea why I'm getting the undefined index notice? :-)

Comment: You are checking if $_FILES is set, but that's a global variable, you should do: `if (isset($_FILES['img'])) {`. Also for each iteration you should check if `$_FILES["img"]["tmp_name"][$key]` is set, or you'll get a notice if you don't upload exactly 3 files.

Comment: Very nice. Thanks a lot for the answer. :D